# How to honor escape sequences the way String() does

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, escaping

I have a string that contains backslashed escape sequences, such as:

```
AB\0C\xff
```

Is there a simple way to parse that that interprets backslashed escape sequences using the same rules as JavaScript string parsing such that the above would generate the byte sequence:

```
0x41 0x42 0x00 0x43 0xff
```

?

I tried `String(line)` but of course that had no effect.

FWIW, here's a short node.js program to demonstrate what I'm after:

```
'use strict'

const readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', function(line) {
  processLine(line);
});

function hexify(line) {
  function hex(v) {
    return ((v < 16) ? '0' : '') + v.toString(16);
  };
  var s=[];
  for (var i=0; i<line.length; i++) {
    s.push(hex(line.charCodeAt(i)));
  };
  return s.join(' ');
}

function honorEscapes(line) {
  return String(line);          // this doesn't do what I want
};

function processLine(line) {
  console.log('raw    ' + hexify(line));
  console.log('parsed ' + hexify(honorEscapes(line)));
};
```

Running it:

```
$ node escape.js
AB\0\C\xff
raw    41 42 5c 30 5c 43 5c 78 66 66
parsed 41 42 5c 30 5c 43 5c 78 66 66
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), which parses [JSON strings](http://json.org/) including escaped characters.

Of course that does not encompass all the weird escapes in [JavaScript string literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-literals-string-literals). Depending on which of those you do need, add them manually for example using regex:

```
.replace(/\\0/g, '\u0000')
.replace(/\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})/g, function(m, c) { return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(c, 16)); }
```

Comment: How did you make this work?  Maybe I'm missing something, but  `JSON.parse('"AB\0\C\xff"')` => `SyntaxError: Unexpected number` at the `0` in the string.

Comment: Ah, right, JSON does not allow all the weird kinds of character escapes that JavaScript string literals allow. You'll have to evaluate null and hex escapes (and everything else you need) manually, e.g. via regex (`.replace(/\\0/g, '\u0000').replace(/\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})/g, function(m, c) { return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(c, 16)); })`)

Comment: Ah - I see.  I could do `JSON.parse('"AB\u0000C\u00ff"')`, which is only a bit of a PITA, or preprocess along the lines you've proposed.  What say you elevate your comment to an edited answer?  :)